# FireBug debugger does not synchronize with the actual javascript code

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

Im having a issue in using firebug to debug javascript code. It doesn't sync with my actual javascript. It comes to the debug mode but doesn't show the exact line where i added the debugger. instead it goes to some other lines in the code.I tried clearing the cache and re-installing firebug but still it doesn't work. any idea ?